# Android front-end not parsing strings properly

Tags: java, android

So, this is my Android MainActivity, but specifically this code:

```
public void checkUser(View view) {
    // Next Activity to move on to
    Intent intentSuccess = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    Intent intentFail = new Intent(this, LoginFailActivity.class);

    EditText usernameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_field);
    String username = usernameText.getText().toString();

    EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword_field);
    String password = passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (username == "admin" && password == "password") {
        startActivity(intentSuccess);
    } else {
        startActivity(intentFail);
    }
}
```

Even when I type in "admin" and "password" it goes to intentFail every time. I have checked with a test activity and it properly passes the strings to it without issue.

Please help me and thank you in advance!!

Comment: Use String equals method to compare string instead of ==. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the problem is here...

```
if (username == "admin" && password == "password")
```

Should be

```
if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("password"))
```

Java treats strings as Objects not char arrays.

Per comment... [Link about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: Just to clarify, using `==` tests if the two `String`s are references to the same object on the heap, whereas `equals()` tests for equality of each character in the `String`s.

Comment: What he said I was debating if my char array comment would hurt the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (username == "admin" && password == "password") {
        startActivity(intentSuccess);
    } else {
        startActivity(intentFail);
    }
```

should be

```
if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("password") {
        startActivity(intentSuccess);
    } else {
        startActivity(intentFail);
    }
```